# How to hide a <dl> item with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a list generated by Wordpress plugin. I want to simply remove the first row of the list, that is the elements  and  through CSS.

This is my html:

```
<dl>
 <dt class="coffee">Coffee</dt>
  <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
 <dt class="milk">Milk</dt>
  <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

I tried `display:none` but it works only for the `<dd>`.

Comment: It dos work http://jsfiddle.net/BBdFn/

Comment: Sorry, my question was not that clear (Too bad I can't edit it...) Anyway I solved it by specifying "!important": dd.coffee, dt.coffee {display:none !important;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want the space occupied by first row you can add this to your css:

```
dt.coffee {
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

If you want to display as if it wasn't there in the first place :

```
dt.coffee {
   display:none;
}
```

In case your definition it's overwritten by a main wordpress style you can check the order of your included css and change it so that your css is the very last included or use  !important:

```
dt.coffee {
   display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you saying you have multiple `dl`'s and you want to delete only the first one?

```
dl:first-of-type{display:none;}
```

Or, are you saying in the `dl` you want to hide the first `dt` and the first `dd`?

```
dl dt:first-child, dl dt:first-child+dd{display:none;}
```

Or are you saying you just want to remove specifically the `dt` and `dd` where the `dt` has the `class` `"coffee"`?

```
.coffee, .coffee+dd{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not put it inline?

```
<dl style="display:none;">
 <dt class="coffee">Coffee</dt>
  <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
 <dt class="milk">Milk</dt>
  <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

but it must really work on your current code. if you put the right css style rule like this

```
dl {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here its should work

Here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r5uWX/

Your css should be

```
dl {
  display: none;
 }
```

and mention the css path depence up on your code. even if it is not working add `!important` like

```
dl {
  display: none !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

for example if this dl is child of a div element you can use this

```
    div.exampleclass dl:first-child {
       display : none
   }
```

for compatibility check this page 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

ps: if you want remove first dt and dd you must use this code :

```
div.exampleclass dl dt:first-child, div.exampleclass dl dd:first-child {
           display : none
       }
```